# How to avoid tight coupling between the CommandName in the XAML and the ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am having multiple views which are databind to single view model.
Now i see a tight coupling with the command name in the different views with the ViewModel.
So i need to avaoid this tight coupling.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Sajesh Nambiar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty normal practice when both View and ViewModel references the same command names, this is like a common protocol/public interface. Look at this from an other point of view, Comamnd Name is like a public interface which supported by both sides - View and ViewModel. So

- If View able to notify an udnerlying ViewModel in a given case it refer to a command by a command name
- If ViewModel able/want to handle any specific command - it exposes a Command via public interface and register it by a Name, providing own command handling logic as well

If we look at Commands from Events standpoint - View able to "raise" a given Command in a particular case and exposes this Event (Command) by specifying it Name (like exposing public event) and this is question of ViewModel whether it would handle such a command (subscribe to Event).

Answer (score 0):

why is there a tight coupling? the viewmodel expose one command and anyone who wants can bind to it. btw mvvm not means that viewmodel and view are not related to each other. they are losely coupled with binding and heavily related to each other.

Comment: yes you are right blindmeis any view can bind to a view model but the designer needs to aware of the name of the Command say for eg...1 view has SelectionChanged event with the command as "testcahngedcommand" now if designer wants to create 1 more View he should know the name "testcahngedcommand" to handle the selection changed event he cant have a name as"dummytestcommand" to invoke the same event..so i was thinking of some interface(or config files) in between Views and the VM which will do this job)..